# Android - Usb CCID large data

Tags: android, usb, smartcard, smartcard-reader, pcsc

How could I notify with bulkTransfer method, when USB protocol is the type T=1, and I receive the answer, that I should repeat reading with the above method instead of making another sending commands? Are there any specific bytes on the curent position, that describes multiple reading? And how could I provide reading more than 64 bytes of packet size (maximum of my USB device MaxPacketSize parameter)?